# Input do tipo date em jQuery

Tags: input, data

Estou procurando uma forma simples de pegar os valores de dia, mês e ano separados a partir de um `input` do tipo `date`, em jQuery.

```js
$( "#ano" ).html($( "input[type=date]" ).val(  ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2018-10-17">
<div id="ano"></div>
```

Como faço para pegar os valores separados sem usar `split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jQuery propriamente, até onde eu saiba, não possui método para isso. O que você pode fazer é converter o valor do campo para o objeto `Date()` do JavaScript e pegar os valores. Basta substituir os hífens por vírgulas e pegar os valores.

> A string deverá estar
> uma formato reconhecido pelo método `Date.parse()` ([IETF-compliant RFC
> 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) e também uma [versão da ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

```js
var input = $("input[type=date]").val().replace(/-/g, ",");
var data = new Date(input);
$( "#ano" ).html( data.getFullYear() );
$( "#mes" ).html( data.getMonth()+1 );
$( "#dia" ).html( data.getDate() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2018-10-17">
<div id="ano"></div>
<div id="mes"></div>
<div id="dia"></div>
```

> É preciso acrescentar +1 no valor do mês porque o JavaScript conta os
> meses à partir do `0`: janeiro = 0, fevereiro = 1 etc.

Comment: Por que tem que acrescentar +1 no mês?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta amigo.

Comment: Muito obrigado!